# jquery slide - how to handle div clicks

Tags: jquery, css

Learning Slide n Hide With Jquery. Unable to paste code, so put a pic instead.

I have a Main div (black), with 3 divs inside it. [All borders all invisible actually].
The blue div has the content and the green is like its tag. The task is to slide the content towards left on green's click.

The slide is working fine. This is how it works now - Only the green tab is visible at page load. Click anywhere inside whole red div, content expands towards left. Click anywhere inside the black div, it collapses.

But this is what I would like to have.
The content div(blue) should expand, only when clicked on divGreen and not anywhere else. And also , it should close if clicked anywhere outside/inside divBlack.
Hope this made some sense.

I tried `$(".divGreen").click(function()`, but the slide doesnt work.

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var r=0, dir=true;
    $(".divBlack").click(function() {
        dir = !dir;
        r = dir? -280 : 0;
        $(this).stop().animate({right: r+'px'}, 800);
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="divBlack">
  <div class="divRed">
     <div class="divGreen"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="divBlue"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

**CSS:**

```
.divBlack
{
position:fixed;
right:-280px;
top:49%;
width:300px;
height:500px;
}
.divGreen
{
float:left;
width:33px;
height:130px;
margin-top:380px;
}
.divBlue
{
float:right;
width:260;
height:500px;
}
```

Comment: try to put z-index:999999; for divGreen, and let me know the result

Comment: Or share with me the code

Comment: Whats the CSS look like?

Comment: because may the divRed is over divGreen, so you actually clicking on divRed not divGreen

Comment: I changed the z-index. It did not work.

Comment: can you share with me the code

Comment: You need to set `position:relative;`

Comment: Cannot have a relative position, as it changes the position of the whole div. Updated the Css, please have a look

Answer (score 1):

Elements have a `static` position cannot be moved. So you need to set `position:relative`

```
.divBlack{
  position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".divGreen").click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
// uour code goes here
});
```

for detail read [e.stoppropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)